# Wordpress ==> SSL ==> MySQL is this configuration possible?

Tags: security, wordpress, mysql

I am trying to put SSL encryption between my Wordpress application and its MySQL database, is anyone aware of a solution/tutorial for this?  Haven't managed to find anything on Google or the Wordpress codex.

Comment: Is Wordpress running on the same server as MySQL?

Comment: Sort of, I have an EC2 server in The US-East with Wordpress + MySQL and need one in US-West and EU-Ireland pointing to the same database so need to encrypt the connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to connect Wordpress to mysql using SSL. Add define('DB_SSL', true); to your wp-config.php file and take a look at this:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-with-mysql-over-ssl

Comment: I found this a couple of days ago on the Wordpress forums but it didn't work for me.  I've double checked MySQL and the SSL is definitely enabled there.

Comment: Considering using SSH tunnels but not sure how stable that would be.

Comment: Getting this to work requires patching the `wp-db.php` class as explained in the linked post on wordpress.org

Comment: This seems to be long out of date.

Answer (score 16):

Further to @ticoombs response, and after some digging / testing, I found that by changing the constant defined in wp-config.php (in the root directory) to the following it worked!

```
define('MYSQL_CLIENT_FLAGS', MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
```

...note the extra "I" in MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSl.

**Symptoms**: The symptom I observed was that the call to mysql_connect in /wp-includes/wp-db.php was generating a warning that parameter 8 (i.e. $client_flags) was not an integer.

**Version**: Vanilla install of 4.8.1, running on php 7.0

Comment: As of Feb 2018, this is all you need to do. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score -2):

Just to build on the answer:

File Location: /wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php

From:

```
$client_flags = defined( 'MYSQL_CLIENT_FLAGS' ) ? MYSQL_CLIENT_FLAGS : 0;
```

To:

```
$client_flags = defined( 'MYSQL_CLIENT_FLAGS' ) ? MYSQL_CLIENT_FLAGS : MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL;
```

Currently WP should be able to handle adding, (below) to the wp-config.php. (But in my findings i have not been able to get it to work.

```
define('MYSQL_CLIENT_FLAGS', MYSQL_CLIENT_SSl);
```

I wrote a good blog post on the matter.
[Source](http://blog.slowb.ro/2013/09/16/enable-ssl-for-db-connections-in-wordpress/)

Comment: Several years late, but do not edit core files! The correct statement in wp-config.php is `define( 'MYSQL_CLIENT_FLAGS', MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL );` (note the **uppercase i** in MYSQL**I**)